# svnadmin:E720023 cant read stream data error cyclic redundancy check

Tags: svn

I am trying to import the SVN dump file of 70GB to another system. after 10 hours of data importing to new system suddenly "svnadmin:E720023  cant read stream data error cyclic redundancy check" issue came and stopped. what is this issue correctly how can i complete this data extraction completely?...Pls help ...